# Бесфигурная — правильно?

Tags: орфография, приставка

Правильно ли такое написание слова *бесфигурная* — с приставкой *бес*-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приставки, заканчивающиеся на **З** или **С**, пишутся так, как слышатся:
через **З** перед звонкими согласными (и гласными) и через **С** перед глухими согласными.
[**Без-** — **бес-**; воз- — вос-; из- — ис-; низ- — нис-; раз- — рас-; через- — черес-.]

Бе**зб**ородый, бе**сп**окойный; и**зд**ание, и**ст**ратить; бе**зв**озмездный, бе**сф**окусный; бе**зв**кусный, бе**сф**орменный; бе**зв**ольный, бе**сф**амильный.

[Правописание приставок](https://lampa.io/p/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA-000000002441639a43a246792dbab5bf)

*Зная, что в таком виде — бе**сф**игурном — ее вряд ли кто-нибудь заметит, если даже люди и попадутся навстречу, она проникла в дом и обошла его, комнату за комнатой.*
В. Михайлов. Властелин

*У нас же тут никаких девок нет — ни фигуристых, ни бе**сф**игурных.*
И. Лорина. Ты подождешь меня там

Comment: "Пишутся так, как слышатся" - не всегда. Безвкусный, например.

Answer (score 0):

В русском языке существуют приставки второй группы - приставки на -*з* и -*с*: *вз- и вс-; воз- и вос-; раз- и рас-* и другие.

В этих приставках пишется *з*, если после неё идёт **звонкая** согласная (*возглас*);

пишется *с*, если после неё **глухая** согласная (*рассказ*).

**В слове *бесфигурная* после приставки следует глухая *ф*, поэтому выбираем бес-.**

Но! На "Стихи.ру" есть такая запись: "Бе*з*фигурная личность..." Почему там З - непонятно. Авторский замысел, авторская изюминка? Даю ссылку: [Стихи.ру](http://www.stihi.ru/2018/10/06/750)